# A definite integral involving odd and even functions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I can't explain myself how $\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} (16 + 24\sin\theta+ 9\sin^2\theta)d\theta$ turns into  $\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} (16 + 9\sin^2\theta) d\theta$, I don't even know if there is some kind of mistake in my book but... what happened to $24 \sin\theta$?

Thank you.

Comment: Well the integral of $24 \sin\theta = 0$ over that range $[-\pi/4, \pi/4]$. Why?

Comment: Is $\sin\theta$ even or odd function? What are the properties of these two classes of functions being integrated over the symmetric interval?

Comment: they are even @Pavel

Comment: @ChristianAndrews: you have the second attempt to answer this question :)

Comment: Lol, thanx @Pavel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral is zero since you integrate over equally large negative and positive parts ($\sin x$ is odd):

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\pi\over 4} 24\sin\theta d\theta =\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{0} 24\sin\theta d\theta +\int_{0}^{\pi\over 4} 24\sin\theta d\theta = 0$$.

Answer (score 1):

The sine function is odd.  So for any $a$ you will have
$$\int_{-a}^a \sin\theta\,d\theta=0\ .$$
To see why either calculate the integral, or even better, draw a graph.